# Getting syntax errors "type XXX could not be resolved" in eclipse CDT while defining union

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm getting a syntax error "type XXX could not be resolved" while defining union and this error won't show up on other IDE like VC++. For example, a union is defined below:

```
typedef union{
    struct {
    int data1;
    int data2;
    int data3;
    } dataField;
    int dataBuffer[sizeof(dataField)];
};
```

A syntax errors happened.

```
type 'dataField' could not be resolved
```

By googling this I found the cause might be the difference between indexers used by eclipse CDT and other IDEs. However, this code still compiles without error.
Could someone give a more specific suggestion to deal with this error message?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
typedef struct
{
   int data1;
   int data2;
   int data3;
} MyData;

typedef union
{
   MyData dataField;
   int dataBuffer[sizeof(MyData)];
} MyUnion;
```

Not sure, but maybe this will work:

```
typedef union
{
   struct DataStruct
   {
      int data1;
      int data2;
      int data3;
   } dataField;
   int dataBuffer[sizeof(struct DataStruct)];
};
```